# Creating fact tables

Tags: ssis, ssas, data-warehouse

I understand the logic behind fact tables and what it should contain. What I would like to know is how to create these fact tables.

Can these fact tables be a view or named query or does it have to be an actual table? What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing one or the other way?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you used a view instead of a table, what tables would you reference in the view? If you can run your reports off a live OLTP database without any data transformation needed and with no impact on performance then you don't need a data warehouse anyway. But if you do need ETL and a star schema that is physically separated from the OLTP system, then you'll have to create those tables.

Comment: The problem right now is running reports off a live OLTP database is a problem on performance. I am new to datawarehouse so I was trying to follow the best practices for creating one. In that sense I was going for the dimensional model and in doing so I didn't understand if fact table had to be an actual table since having a view serve as a fact table would mean easier maintenance for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *technically*, a fact table can be a view or named query.

Advantages

- no additional disk space required :-)
- zero data-availability latency (data is available as soon as it is inserted into your source)

Disadvantages

- does not scale
- slower query response speed (varies based on complexity of view definition)
- does not scale
- increased maintenance complexity (this is HUGE btw)
- does not scale
- reduced flexibility
- no surrogate keys
- no type2 SCDs
- indexing issues
- **does not scale**

FWIW - I've build a small star-schema (3 fact tables, 10 dimensions) using views but it was simply for a proof of concept and I strongly oppose this for production use.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much. Right now I am just prototyping and I think I am just going to use views to get myself more familiar and for ease of iterative testing and development. When I am confident about what the actual requirements are and how I want to set it up, I will go ahead and create fact tables properly.

Comment: you're welcome.  also, if you haven't already, pick up a copy of The Data Warehouse Toolkit...its the bible for DW-(star-schema)-modeling.